# $\forall H, \exists G\unrhd H$ with automorphisms of $H$ obtained by restricting inner automorphisms of $G$ to $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

> 18. Show that if $H$ is any group then there is a group $G$ that contains $H$ as a normal subgroup with the property that for every automorphism $\sigma$ of $H$ there is an element $g\in G$ such that conjugation by $g$ when restricted to $H$ is the given automorphism $\sigma$, i.e., every automorphism of $H$ is obtained as an inner automorphism of $G$ restricted to $H$.

For $G=H\rtimes_\varphi K$, view $G$ as the set of ordered pairs $\{(h,k)\}$ s.t. $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(h_1(\varphi(k_1)(h_2)),k_1k_2)$

My guess is that $G=\operatorname{Hol}(H)=H\rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(H)$. For example, let $H=\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2=\{1,x,y,xy\}$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(H)\cong S_3$, where each symmetry permutes the $3$ non-identity elements of $H$. $G=\operatorname{Hol}(H)=(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)\rtimes_\varphi S_3$:$$\varphi:S_3\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)\cong S_3$$$$\varphi(12)=\sigma_{(12)}:x\mapsto y,y\mapsto x,xy\mapsto xy$$$$\varphi(123)=\sigma_{(123)}:x\mapsto y,y\mapsto xy,xy\mapsto x$$$$\vdots$$

We kind of embed both $H$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ in a larger group, in this case $G=\operatorname{Hol}(H)\cong S_4$, and $H\unlhd G$. Every automorphism $\sigma$ of $H=\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ appears in the codomain of $\varphi$ and it corresponds to exactly one element in $S_3$ ($\varphi$ is a bijection). If we see $S_3$ as a subgroup of $S_4$, then $\sigma$ corresponds to $g=(1,\sigma)\in G$ s.t. conjugation by $g=(1,\sigma)$ when restricted to $H$ is $\sigma$, because this is exactly how we define a semidirect product: $K$ acts on $H$ by conjugation. e.g. $\sigma_{(12)}:x\mapsto y,y\mapsto x,xy\mapsto xy$ corresponds to the ordered pair $g=(1,(12))\in G$ s.t. conjugation by $g$ when restricted to $H$ (used during construction of the semidirect product) is $\sigma_{(12)}$.

Is my guess correct? I know the example looks clumsy but I want to know if there is any problem with the above. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but the holomorph is the best way to solve this problem in general. For individual groups $H$, there may be smaller possibilities for $G$. For example, if $H$ is a group with trivial centre, then you can embed $H$ into its full automorphism group.

Comment: @DerekHolt I understand that there may be smaller groups $G$ for a particular $H$. When I first encountered this problem, I thought of the symmetric group $S_n$. For $n\neq 6$, every automorphism of $S_n$ is inner, so we can let $H=G=S_n$

Comment: This problem is easy to understand, but I fear that I may have gone into some circular argument trap or something like that, that's why I'm here to ask for verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

Generally if you take a groups $H$ and $K$, and a group homomorphism $f: K \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H)$, you can use $(H,K,f)$ to form the semidirect product $G = H \rtimes_f K$.

Then some basic facts you can check using the definitions:

- $H' = \{(h,1) : h \in H \}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, isomorphic to $H$.
- $K' = \{(1,k) : k \in K \}$ is a subgroup of $G$, isomorphic to $K$.
- Every element $g \in G$ induces a automorphism of $H'$ via conjugation, hence an automorphism of $H$.
- For $k \in K$, conjugation by $(1,k)$ induces an automorphism of $H'$ which corresponds to the automorphism $f(k)$ of $H$.

In particular if you take $K = \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ and $f$ to be the identity map, the semidirect product $G$ is (by definition) the holomorph. It should be immediate that in this semidirect product $G$, conjugation by elements of $K'$ gives you every automorphism of $H$.

Comment: Yea, I'm glad that someone confirms my belief. What's more, today I realised that if we don't take $K=\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, the map $\varphi$ may not be a bijection and so some automorphisms of $H$ may not be obtained by restricting inner automorphisms of $G$ to $H$.

Comment: @hellotinfish: correct. Actually you just need $f$ to be surjective, and of course the easiest to way to that is to take the identity map $\operatorname{Aut}(H) \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ (which gives the holomorph).